# In a longitundinal dataframe, I found the max value for each row. Now I need to retrieve columns associated with the max. In R

Tags: r, max, longitudinal

I have a longitudinal dataframe that look like this :

```
ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
Grade_06 <- c(1000,900,850,1200,450,600)
Age_06 <- c(17,25,36,12,22,44)
Grade_07 <- c(900,1010,423,1500,125,564)
Age_07 <- c(18,26,37,13,23,45)
Grade_08 <- c(847,1111,568,450,1300,641)
Age_08 <- c(19,27,38,14,24,46)
Grade_09 <- c(1451,820,650,740,910,1000)
Age_09 <- c(20,28,39,15,25,47)

df <- as.data.frame(ID, Grade_06, Age_06, Grade_07, Age_07, Grade_08, Age_08, Grade_09, Age_09)
```

I found the max of each row using :

```
df <- within(df, {Best_grade=pmax(Grade_06, Grade_07, Grade_08, Grade_09, na.rm = TRUE)})
```

Now, that the max has been found, I need to associate the max of each row with the age of the people when they reach their max grade.

I really struggle with this. Can you help?

Comment: In the representative data frame you provided, are those all the Age/Gender columns that you have? Or (for example) do you have a Grade_10 and Age_10 that we need to account for in the solution?

Comment: @HarrisonJones I do have more columns. Basically, my real dataset goes from 06 to 21.

Answer (score 0):

The following gives you a data frame with the ID and Grade column names where it equals `Best_grade`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(across(contains('Grade_'), function(x) x == Best_grade)) %>%
  split(df$ID) %>%
  map_dfr(function(x) {
    x_grades_only <- x %>% select(contains('Grade_'))
    tibble(ID = x$ID, Grade = names(x_grades_only)[as.logical(x_grades_only)])
  })
```